# Django admin panel error when update a post "'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'"

Tags: python, django

I want to create a inventory system. In this system admin can add medicine to database. I used admin panel for that. So, I add/delete/update the medicine from django **admin panel only**. I can add or delete a medicine easily but when I try update it, there is an error:

> AttributeError at /admin/medicines/medicine/18/change/ 'bytes' object
> has no attribute '_committed'

How can I fixed it?

**models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.utils.text import slugify
    
    
    class Medicine(models.Model):
    
        medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        medicine_info = RichTextField(verbose_name="notes")
        medicine_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        medicine_qr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        medicine_price = models.IntegerField()
        medicine_stock = models.IntegerField()
        medicine_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img_medicine', null=True, blank=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)
    
        def get_image(self):
            if self.medicine_image and hasattr(self.medicine_image, 'url'):
                return self.medicine_image.url
            else:
                return
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.medicine_name
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['medicine_name']
    
        def get_create_url(self):
            return reverse('medicines:medicine_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    
        def get_unique_slug(self):
            slug = slugify(self.slug.replace('ı', 'i'))
            unique_slug = slug
            counter = 1
            while Medicine.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
                unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
                counter += 1
            return unique_slug
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('medicines:medicine_create', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
            return super(Medicine, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
 class MedicineForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Medicine
            fields = [
                'medicine_name',
                'medicine_info',
                'medicine_code',
                'medicine_price',
                'medicine_stock',
                'medicine_image',
    
            ]
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/medicines/medicine/18/change/

Django Version: 2.2.13
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'patients',
 'medicines',
 'blog',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
      606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
      223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
      1648.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
      45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
      1529.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
      1572.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_model
      1088.         obj.save()
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\pharsys\medicines\models.py" in save
      47.         return super(Medicine, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
      741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
      779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
      848.                       for f in non_pks]
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in <listcomp>
      848.                       for f in non_pks]
    
    File "C:\Users\edeni\senior\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
      286.         if file and not file._committed:
    
    Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/medicines/medicine/18/change/
    Exception Value: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Medicine
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Medicine)
```

Comment: Can you share your admin.py too?

Comment: @IainShelvington I add it.